# time measurement execution and allocation in gpu

Tags: java, opencl, gpu, jocl

I am execution a parallel kernel on GPU using OpenCL and JOCL.

**I want to know:**

1/ Is there any functions to know the kernel size in term of work-items and work groups and how it is executed in my Nvidia GPU platform?

2/ is there a possibility to know the execution time of the kernel without GPU/CPU data transfers because? I used java tools `System.currentTimeMillis();`
before starting the kernel and after but it includes the data transfers time.

3/ more precisely is there any possibility to know the execution time of each GPU core?

Comment: There is a dedicated example showing how to obtain the execution time of kernels using events, at http://jocl.org/samples/JOCLEventSample.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  In kernel,

```
get_global_size(0) gives number of items in x dimension
get_global_size(1) gives number of item arrays in y dimension
get_global_size(2) gives number of item matrices in z dimension
```

total number is multiplication of them but if kernel is launched only 1-dim then only first function is enough.

```
get_local_size(0 or 1 or 2);
```

gives same thing for items in groups, not total items.

```
get_num_groups (0 or 1 or 2)
```

is similar but gives number of groups in total groups.

Number of dimensions are taken from

```
 int dims=get_work_dim ()
```

2) Event based performance queries from host code:

http://www.jocl.org/cloth/docs/doc-utils/org/jocl/utils/Events.html

computeExecutionTimeMs(org.jocl.cl_event event) 
          Compute the execution time for the given event, in milliseconds.

1), 2) and 3) a profiler

can show all except "each core"(but gives info of "Lanes" which may not map to same core at all times but you can see what a single thread was doing) part. https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition  visuals and tables give enough information about bottlenecks and kernel hotspots

Comment: Thank you, I have a question about the profiler, Can I use it with eclipse?? In the link they cited just Visual studio.

Comment: If that is working as "attached" to a process, then there is a chance to attach it to jvm or something related to jar executing process. Maybe somekind of command-line running from visual studio could work too.